# problem with replacing (part of) string by iterating through list (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, replace

There must be a simple answer to this...Python newbie here.

```
country_list = [('KOREA, REPUBLIC OF','KOREA'),('RUSSIAN FEDERATION','RUSSIA'),('TAIWAN, PROVINCE OF CHINA','TAIWAN'),('BOLIVARIAN REPUBLIC OF','BOLIVIA'),('CÔTE D\'IVOIRE','IVORY COAST')]
korea = ('KOREA, REPUBLIC OF','KOREA')
s1= 'I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF'
s2 = s1.replace(korea[0],korea[1])
for country in country_list:
   s3 = s1.replace(country[0],country[1])
print('s2:',s2)
print('s3:',s3)
```

When I run this, s2 is what I expect:  'I like KOREA'.
But s3 remains the same as s1, when I expected it to be the same as s2.  In other words, nothing gets replaced.
What am I doing wrong?
Here's the output:

```
s2: I like KOREA
s3: I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
```

(If I use lists instead of tuples to hold my country names, I get the same results.)

(By way of background, I've actually got a long list of sublists, the latter containing strings, with country names occupying a specific place in each sublist.  So I was planning to iterate through country_list and use the replace() method...but it doesn't seem to work, for some reason.)

EDIT/UPDATE:
Based on answers below (thank you!) I've realised that one way to solve this is:

```
s3 = s1
for country in country_list:
   s3 = s3.replace(country[0],country[1])
print('s2:',s2)
print('s3:',s3)
```

Comment: Issue is in your for loop you keep replacing the initial s1 i.e. `s3 = s1.replace(country[0],country[1])`.  So the result will be for the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are overriding `s3` in each iteration on the different countries. If the `replace` method doesn't find any match, it does nothing. Therefore, replace is modifying `s1` (and assigns the result to `s3`) only in the first iteration (when Korea is the case) and in the next iterations it does nothing as expected, because it didn't find any match. It is easy to see this with the following code:

```py
country_list = [('KOREA, REPUBLIC OF','KOREA'),('RUSSIAN FEDERATION','RUSSIA'),('TAIWAN, PROVINCE OF CHINA','TAIWAN'),('BOLIVARIAN REPUBLIC OF','BOLIVIA'),('CÔTE D\'IVOIRE','IVORY COAST')]
korea = ('KOREA, REPUBLIC OF','KOREA')
s1= 'I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF'
s2 = s1.replace(korea[0],korea[1])
print('s2:',s2)

for country in country_list:
    s3 = s1.replace(country[0],country[1])
    print('s3:',s3)
```

The above prints the following:

```
s2: I like KOREA
s3: I like KOREA
s3: I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
s3: I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
s3: I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
s3: I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following assignment:

```py
s3 = s1.replace(country[0],country[1])
```

You are always assigning `s3` to replacement operation of `s1`.  But since you iterate over every country, `s3` will only retain the *last* country replacement.  Instead, you should initialize `s3` to `s1`, and then assign `s3` to a replacement of itself.

```py
country_list = [('KOREA, REPUBLIC OF','KOREA'),('RUSSIAN FEDERATION','RUSSIA'),('TAIWAN, PROVINCE OF CHINA','TAIWAN'),('BOLIVARIAN REPUBLIC OF','BOLIVIA'),('COTE D\'IVOIRE','IVORY COAST')]
korea = ('KOREA, REPUBLIC OF','KOREA')
s1 = 'I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF'
s2 = s1.replace(korea[0],korea[1])
s3 = s1
for country in country_list:
    s3 = s3.replace(country[0],country[1])
print('s2:',s2)  # ('s2:', 'I like KOREA')
print('s3:',s3)  # ('s3:', 'I like KOREA')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `s1` stays the same in the loop but `s3` changes. When you iterate over the list, it does replace the provided string. That new string is assigned to `s3`

But you did not change `s1`, so `s1` still has the same value. In the next iteration, `.replace` doesn't find any substring provided, so it returns the string as it is. **This new value or the unchanged string is assigned to `s3` again and the previously assigned string is dumped**. This goes on until the list ends.

That is why you get that result.

One possible work around is:

1. Create a copy of the string `s1` and assign it to `s3`
2. Assign the returned value of the `.replace` function to `s3` again:

```
s3=s1[:]
for country in country_list:
    s3 = s3.replace(country[0],country[1])
```

The output of your code:

```
I like KOREA
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
```

Since iterators only go forward, you can see that python had replaced the string. But when you iterated again, this string was dumped and the new "unreplaced" string returned by `.replace` was assigned to `s3`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running the loop, the value `s3` gets assigned replacing original value of `s1` at each iteration, you are not storing the previously replaced string. You can print `s3` in the loop to verify it:

```py
for country in country_list:
    print(country)
    print(s1)
    s3 = s1.replace(country[0],country[1])
    print(s3)
    print('#############')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
('KOREA, REPUBLIC OF', 'KOREA')
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA
#############
('RUSSIAN FEDERATION', 'RUSSIA')
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
#############
('TAIWAN, PROVINCE OF CHINA', 'TAIWAN')
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
#############
('BOLIVARIAN REPUBLIC OF', 'BOLIVIA')
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
#############
("CÔTE D'IVOIRE", 'IVORY COAST')
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
#############
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put `s3` in a for loop, `s3` value after loop is the last value of it

So in first iterate, `s3` is 'I LIKE KOREA' as you want. But after that, 'KOREA, REPUBLIC OF' can't be found in `s1` so `s3` would be reset to `s1`

As you can see this in :

```py
for country in country_list:
    s3 = s1.replace(country[0],country[1])
    print(s3)
```

Will give you:

```
I like KOREA
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
```

You can do sth like:

```py
s3 = s1
for country in country_list:
    s3 = s3.replace(country[0],country[1])
```

Comment: Thanks to EVERYONE for your prompt and sensible answers.  Thanks to you I can see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You replace function is looking for the string in country[0] inside s1, and as it does not find it, it does not replace any text.

For example: your second country ('RUSSIAN FEDERATION', 'RUSSIA').

Replace tries to find 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION' inside 'I like KOREA, REPUBLIC OF'. As it does not find, no replace is done, and so every s3 is equal to s1.

You may want to make s1 = "I like" and simply concatenate the result with the country of the iteration. This is a suggestion and I don't know if that solves the problem, but the reason why it is "not working" is above.